# What are `Developmental Milestones` for programming skills?

Tags: self-improvement

I studied in the field of Computer Science for 6 years,  bachelor's degree and master's degree. I have studied all the basic programming like C, Java, VB, C#, Python, and etc. When I have free times, I will learn new programming languages and follow new programming trends by myself , such as PHP, HTML5, CSS5, LESS, Bootstrap, Symfony2, and GitHub. So, if someone wants me to write some instructions using these languages, I'm certain that I can do it, not so good but I can get a job done. However, I don't have any favorite programming language. Moreover, I also have studied about algorithms, database, and etc.

Everything I just wrote so far seems that I know a lot in this field. In fact, I feel I am very stupid. I cannot answer 80% of the questions on SO. In spite of those languages​​, I have studied. Perhaps it is because I have never worked before.

---

As there is the `Developmental Milestones` for children, which refers to how a child becomes able to do more complex things as they get older, I would like to evaluate the same thing but for programming skills. What are the set of functional skills or age-specific tasks that most programmers can do at a certain age range?

In order to evaluate myself, I would like to ask your opinions that all of the skills I mentioned above, are they enough for programmers to know when they are 25 years old?

What are your suggestions in order to improve the skills in this field?

Comment: Age is a *very* poor indicator of programmer ability.  You might want to look at the [programmer competency matrix](http://sijinjoseph.com/programmer-competency-matrix/), though what you are really asking for doesn't exist.

Comment: Computer science have nothing to do with learning languages and frameworks. No connection whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

> I have studied all the basic programming like C, Java, VB, C#, Python, and etc.

This tells me you've not quite understood what Computer Science is at it's core.. All it is, is 0's and 1's... slinging bits around.  Just because you've studied something for X years doesn't mean you understand the underpinnings of a technology..

Focus on things at the core.  What would get you a job at the top computer firms in the world? Google, Apple, etc...

- Algorithms
- Data Structures
- Big O analysis

You've mentioned very little of these things, yet they are the core of computer science.

Again, stop comparing yourself on an age scale, and just have fun with computer science.  I cannot answer 90% of the things on Stack Overflow.. but I am calm because that's not my (or your) job.. focus on what you want to accomplish with computers, and science, and relax..